# Passing dynamic color to Material-UI Icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The properties (like font awesome classes, color as HUE) of the icons I want to display are defined in a JSON file like:

```
"users": {"icon":"fas fa-users",
            "iconcolor":"green"}
```

Then for each icon, I tried this without success.

```
<Icon className={icon} style={{ color: {iconcolor}[500] }} fontSize="small"></Icon>
```

It compiles but icons are still displayed in primary style.
Am I doing something wrong here ? How to make work ?

Comment: It will now work like this, Because you are passing green as text not as actual green color. the way you can do is. import material ui green color and based on iconcolor data you can supply the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first import the color from material ui

```
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green;

var selectedColor = {iconcolor} === 'green' ? green : purple
<Icon className={icon} style={{ color: {selectedColor}[500] }} fontSize="small"></Icon>
```

you can use switch case as well. or you can store the color code in the user data.

Comment: thx for your help. This is my prefered answer, because it leverages the already defined colors and keeps the abstraction I need. I will indeed create a utility function that convert raw color strings to imported ones from Material UI. This way it is more flexible if I want to change the style from [500] to another one later on...

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
<Icon className={icon} style={{ color: {iconcolor}[500] }} fontSize="small"></Icon>
```

you should pass the actual color...

```
<Icon className={icon} style={{ color: iconcolor}} fontSize="small"></Icon>
```

this is only if the default css color naming are supporting this color as a name..
you can additionally send a hex (`#ffffff` for white for example)  color or rgb colors:

```
<Icon className={icon} style={{ color: 'rgb(255,0,0)'}} fontSize="small"></Icon>
```

Note: the `green[500]` you see in [this docs](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#font-material-icons) is using material-ui's library of colors which generates a string like i showed you...